# jquery condition

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

here is my exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/moolood/jLfxD/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="child1" name="child1" value="" >
<input type="text" id="child2" name="child2" value="">
<input type="text" id="child3" name="child3" value="">

<button id="button">check</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    if ($('input[name^="child"]').val().length == 0) {
        alert('one or several fields are empty');
    }
    else {
        alert('good!!!');
    }
});
```

What i'm trying to do is to execute something if all the input wich name begins with "child" have a value > 0.

In my exemple i have notice that it execute something if just one of the 3 input value length is superior to 0.

How to write the code for ALL the 3 fields value length have to be more than 0?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's performing the comparison on the first matched element.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.is` with a function: http://jsfiddle.net/jLfxD/1/.

```
var isEmpty = function() {
    return $(this).val().length === 0;
};

$('#button').click(function() {
    if ($('input[name^="child"]').is(isEmpty)) {
        // if one or more are empty: `.is` returns true
        // as soon as one element satisfies the function
        alert('one or several fields are empty');
    }
    else {
        alert('good!!!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following assuming you are just checking the length.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var accepted = true;
    $('input[name^="child"]').each(function(i) {
        accepted= $(this).val().length > 0 && accepted;
    });

    alert(accepted);

});
```

If you need to check for values of numbers greater than 0 (hard to tell by your question) you can try to parseInt the value and do your check.

​

Answer (score 0):

It's performing the comparison on the first matched element. You can use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to perform the condition on every matched element.

```
var children = $('input[name^="child"]').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).val().length == 0;
});

if (children.length > 0)
{
    alert('one or several fields are empty')
}
```